# Is it possible to use ExecuteQuery without Load?

Tags: csom

I have the following little routine that uploads a document to SharePoint 2019 on premises and works fine. But I don't understand why it works without a **clientContext.Load(uploadFile)** statement.

How is this possible? Here's the routine:

Private Shared Sub UpToSharePoint(ByVal docName As String, _
ByVal siteUrl As String, _
ByVal weekEndingDt As Date, _
ByVal docBytes As Byte())

```
    Using clientContext As New Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext(siteUrl)
        Dim documentsList As Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List = 
               clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("StatusReports")

        Dim fileCreationInformation As New Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation

        fileCreationInformation.Content = docBytes
        fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = True
        fileCreationInformation.Url = siteUrl & "/" & "StatusReports" & "/" & docName & ".pdf"

        Dim uploadFile As Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File = 
              documentsList.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation)

        uploadFile.ListItemAllFields("WeekEndingDt") = weekEndingDt
        uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update()

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

    End Using

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Load()` is generally needed when you are fetching data and not when you are creating or modifying data - in other words, when you're pulling and not pushing data. There might be edge cases I'm not thinking of but if it works without `Load()` then you do not need it.

Comment: Interesting. Every example I can find on ther internet includes .LOAD